# Merging similar Android apps into one project and build two different apps out of it

Tags: android

Say I have two apps which are very similar: One to spot/register birds, the other for plants. Approx. 80% of both apps are the same. The differences lay in the differences in properties of the two species. This leads to differences in: a few entities, db loading assets, 2 layouts, strings, launcher icons and a few features (eg. playing songs, loading media).

I've read docs/blogs about modules/libraries, but haven't had an 'aha' moment yet...

Question: What would be the best approach to merge the two apps and build two apps using different fragments, layouts, entities etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Created a workable solution using [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) instead of using modules.

Using product flavors the app has three folders 'main', 'birds' and 'plants'. Folder 'main' contains all code/resources/assets that are common to both flavors. Folders 'birds' and 'plants' contain code/resources/assets that are unique to the specific flavor.

Depending on the flavor selected, Gradle combines 'main'/'plants' or 'main'/'birds' to create the app.